# tableview to web video

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am doing a table view with video.
the video are from web.
i make an array of the link and all work fine.
the really problem is:
when I select the cell I go to the youtube page and then I have to press the play button for watch the video.
I wanna know how to watch directly the video pressing the cell without see the youtube page.
maybe a `MediaPlayer Framework`?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all information you need on the following web page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/